# Running a script from Java

Tags: java, cygwin

I have a number of scripts that I run on `Windows` through `cygwin`.

These script files always require manual editing whenever I take a new sandbox.

Thus, I was thinking of writing a little `Java` UI app that will edit the scripts automatically based on a users UI settings.

I've read a few other posts regarding running a script file from `Java` but didn't see any on how to run them on `Windows` through `cygwin`.

Has anyone else done this or know of a previous post that they could refer me to?

Comment: Are you trying to edit a file, or run a script?

Comment: I'm trying to run a script but assumed I could do the editing of the files from within Java based on the user entered settings from a UI.

Answer (score 0):

If `cygwin` is on your path, you can execute it like any other external program from Java.

**Note:** You have to **read the streams from parallel threads** in real code! This is just a **proof of concept** for running a bash script through cygwin on windows!

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c ./script.sh");
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: You suggest "you can execute it like any other external program from Java".

When running a Linux script on Windows I have to: 1) run cygwin 2) from a cygwin session cd /cygdrive/d/.... to where the script file resides 3) run the script ./script ...

I can't see how all of this is run like any other command on Windows; eg:

.exec("./script.sh");

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the `Cygwin.bat` file found in the Cygwin install directory you will see your session turns into a Cygwin session and you can then run all the commands you can in a cygwin session.

If you then add the `cygwin/bin` directory to your path, you can execute commands directly like a linux environment.

In my case I added the following to the end of my PATH system variable `C:\cygwin64\bin`, and I can now run `bash` and other commands directly like a normal session.